# Recoding groups to create a summary accordingly

Tags: r

I have a data like table below

```
Category Value
14        1
13        2
32        1
63        4
24        1
77        3
51        2
19        4
15        1
24        4
32        3
10        1
.         .
.         .
so on
```

actually i want to create a group of variables like

```
C1= (14,13,24,19,77)
C2= (32,51,63,15,10)
c3= (......)
c4= (...)
```

so that it will create a dataframe like (Recoding kind of thing)

```
C1  c2  c3  c4......
14  32  
13  51
24  63
15  10
```

after this i can create a summary

```
df<- df[!is.na(df[[cols]]), ]
sum1 <- as.data.frame(table(df[[cols]]))
```

Final Expected output should be like

```
   C1  C2 C3 ....
1  22%
2  13%
3  42%
4  15%
N  94
```

N is total number of counts for that particular groups.

Comment: just updated output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a column to group various values from `C1`, `C2` etc and give them their respective value. We can then get the data in wide format. You can use `adorn_totals` from `janitor` to get sum of each column added in the last row.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(col = case_when(Category %in% C1 ~ 'C1', 
                           Category %in% C2 ~ 'C2')) %>%
  mutate(Value = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = Category) %>%
  janitor::adorn_totals()
```

Comment: getting error

Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: can we do dynamic for selecting groups so that it can be a function for me ....

Comment: Are you sure you are copying the answer correctly and it does not have any typos?

Comment: Then you probably need to provide a reproducible example using `dput`. Read how to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269